# Register and Login procedures in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm creating a database to host user credentials and other data with PHPMyAdmin 5.1.1, for a school project. For the Registration and Login I wanted to use Stored Procedures to ensure some degree of security instead of splitting the functions between MySQL and PHP like many other examples on the web. Not sure if it is actually a good implementation since I didn't found many other examples where the entire Login is made with MySQL.

I am using sha1 to hash the passwords concatenated with randomly generated salt.

My table is made like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `credentials` (
`Code` int(32) NOT NULL,
`Email` varchar(48) NOT NULL,
`Passwd` binary(40) NOT NULL,
`Salt` binary(20) NOT NULL,
`Date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

The two procedures I have wrote:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Register_new_user` (IN `mail` VARCHAR(48), IN 
`pass` VARCHAR(48))  NO SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE `salt` BINARY(20);
    SET `salt`=SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()), -24);
    INSERT INTO `credentials`(`Email`,`Passwd`, `Salt`) VALUES(`mail`, SHA1(CONCAT(`pass`,`salt`)),`salt`);
END$$


CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Log_in` (IN `mail` VARCHAR(48), IN `pass` 
VARCHAR(48), OUT `responseMessage` VARCHAR(64), OUT `ID` INT(32))  NO SQL
BEGIN
   DECLARE `salt` BINARY(20);
   SET `ID`=NULL;

   IF (EXISTS(SELECT `Code` FROM `credentials` WHERE BINARY `Email`=`mail` ORDER BY `Code` DESC LIMIT 1))
   THEN
       SET `salt`=(SELECT `Salt` FROM `credentials` WHERE BINARY `Email`=`mail`);
       SET `ID`=(SELECT `Code` FROM `credentials` WHERE BINARY `Email`=`mail` AND BINARY `Passwd`=SHA1(CONCAT(`Pass`,`salt`)));
       IF(`ID` IS NULL) THEN
           SET `responseMessage`='wrong password';
       ELSE
           SET `responseMessage`='Success';
       END IF;

   ELSE
       SET `responseMessage`='Error';
   END IF;
END$$

DELIMETER;
```

I'm not sure why this is not working. Every time I test the Login procedure with the right credentials it always output "wrong password". If I test manually the comparison of the stored password with the sha1 output it looks to me identical, so I don't know why it fails.

```
 SET @p=(SELECT `salt` FROM `credentials` WHERE `Email`="AAAA");
 SELECT SHA1(CONCAT("banana",@p));
 SELECT `Passwd` FROM `credentials` WHERE `Email`="AAAA";
```

This test return for the first and second select:

```
b6830fcf435250097bfa6233a47fded36fb33f17
b6830fcf435250097bfa6233a47fded36fb33f17
```

Please, can anybody point out what am I doing wrong? Could it be the format or size of the binary I store? Or what else?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not going to give my opinions on whether this amounts to a good or bad implementation. There are plenty of good discussions on this topic on SO.

There are a number of reasons why this is not working and you should have received a number of error messages when trying your code.

1. What is your intent with `Code int(32)` - Integer display width is deprecated and an integer has a maximum unsigned value of 4,294,967,295 - [11.1.2 Integer Types (Exact Value)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html)
2. I am not sure why you are using binary for `Passwd` and `Salt` as you are currently storing the hex string values. If you want to benefit from the more efficient storage you need to [UNHEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_unhex) the values before storing them. In this case your `Passwd` could be stored in BINARY(20) and `Salt` could be stored in BINARY(12). Have a look at [11.3.3 The BINARY and VARBINARY Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-varbinary.html).
3. Both stored procs are declared as `NO SQL` when the first should be `MODIFIES SQL DATA` as it inserts data, and the second should be `READS SQL DATA` as it SELECTs data. This is not a big issue as MySQL treats these characteristics as advisory only.
4. You declare salt as BINARY(20) and then try to assign a 24 character string -  `SET salt = SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()), -24);`
5. In your table declaration `Code` is `NOT NULL` but your INSERT statement does not specify a value for `Code`.
6. Your use of email when searching for credentials suggests there should be a unique index.
7. Column names are not case sensitive so when you `SET salt=(SELECT Salt FROM credentials WHERE BINARY Email=mail);` you are SELECTing the local variable not the table column.

Here's a modified table declaration -

```sql
CREATE TABLE `credentials` (
    `Code` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `Email` VARCHAR(48) NOT NULL,
    `Passwd` BINARY(40) NOT NULL,
    `Salt` BINARY(24) NOT NULL,
    `Date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
    UNIQUE INDEX `UQ_credentials_email` (`Email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

And the stored procedures -

```sql
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Register_new_user`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `Register_new_user` (
    IN `mail` VARCHAR(48),
    IN `pass` VARCHAR(48)
)
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE `_salt` BINARY(24);
    SET `_salt` = SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()), -24);
    INSERT INTO `credentials`(`Email`, `Passwd`, `Salt`) VALUES (`mail`, SHA1(CONCAT(`pass`, `_salt`)), `_salt`);
END$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Log_in`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `Log_in` (
    IN `mail` VARCHAR(48),
    IN `pass` VARCHAR(48),
    OUT `responseMessage` VARCHAR(64),
    OUT `ID` INT
)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
   DECLARE `_salt` BINARY(24);
   SET `ID` = NULL;

   SELECT `Salt` INTO `_salt` FROM `credentials` WHERE `Email` = `mail`;
   IF (`_salt` IS NOT NULL)
   THEN
       SELECT `Code` INTO `ID` FROM `credentials` WHERE `Email` = `mail` AND `Passwd` = SHA1(CONCAT(`Pass`, `_salt`));
       IF(`ID` IS NULL) THEN
           SET `responseMessage` = 'wrong password';
       ELSE
           SET `responseMessage` = 'Success';
       END IF;

   ELSE
       SET `responseMessage`='Error';
   END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Or to make more efficient use of the BINARY storage -

```sql
CREATE TABLE `credentials` (
    `Code` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `Email` VARCHAR(48) NOT NULL,
    `Passwd` BINARY(20) NOT NULL,
    `Salt` BINARY(12) NOT NULL,
    `Date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
    UNIQUE INDEX `UQ_credentials_email` (`Email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

and the stored procedures modified with HEX() and UNHEX() as required -

```sql
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Register_new_user`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `Register_new_user` (
    IN `mail` VARCHAR(48),
    IN `pass` VARCHAR(48)
)
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE `_salt` CHAR(24);
    SET `_salt` = SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()), -24);
    INSERT INTO `credentials`(`Email`, `Passwd`, `Salt`) VALUES (`mail`, UNHEX(SHA1(CONCAT(`pass`, `_salt`))), UNHEX(`_salt`));
END$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Log_in`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `Log_in` (
    IN `mail` VARCHAR(48),
    IN `pass` VARCHAR(48),
    OUT `responseMessage` VARCHAR(64),
    OUT `ID` INT
)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
   DECLARE `_salt` CHAR(24);
   SET `ID` = NULL;

   SELECT LOWER(HEX(`Salt`)) INTO `_salt` FROM `credentials` WHERE `Email` = `mail`;
   IF (`_salt` IS NOT NULL)
   THEN
       SELECT `Code` INTO `ID` FROM `credentials` WHERE `Email` = `mail` AND `Passwd` = UNHEX(SHA1(CONCAT(`Pass`, `_salt`)));
       IF(`ID` IS NULL) THEN
           SET `responseMessage` = 'wrong password';
       ELSE
           SET `responseMessage` = 'Success';
       END IF;

   ELSE
       SET `responseMessage`='Error';
   END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I'm not much familiar with MySQL and referenced some other examples from the web. I see why I did those errors and your answer was actually really helpful, thanks!
My code didn't report any error as I exported the working one from phpmyadmin.

2. `Binary` becouse I saw almost everyone use it to store those values. I already tried to use HEX and UNHEX but I guess I didn't understood how to properly use them as I couldn't figure out if it was already unhexed or not when I was storing it.

Comment: Sha1 uses 160 bits, so the hash can be memorized in `BINARY(20)`. When I tried to debug with the query I posted at the end of my post, I noticed that I stored 20 but the sha1 returned 40 characters. That's why set 40. I guess maybe `CONCAT` does not trim the data lenght as I expected and instead of generating one encrypted block I genereted two of them.

3.I had no idea what was that for. I guessed if the procedure could accept SQL code as input and I set it to NO to avoid SQL Injection lol.

Comment: 5. This never resulted a problem to me because `Code` is set as auto increment. It should be set automatically when the insertion event is performed, right? It always worked like this to me.
      7.I guess this and UNHEX where the major problem that caused my code to not work.

Comment: @Khaleeja 4 and 5 were the obvious problems. It took me a few minutes to figure out what was going on with 7. Never use local variables with the same name as your columns or tables as it can make debugging and readability a nightmare. I normally prefix all my local variables with an underscore but people have their own preferences. Your example table declaration did not include the auto_increment primary key or a unique index on email. We all learn by reading the examples of other people but it is important to understand the examples, not just blindly copy them.